# OCCI exception: connect descriptor is too long (but not really)

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I'm using OCCI for working with Oracle database by C++ and I'm trying to create a connection like this:

```
#include <occi.h>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);    
    Connection *con = env->createConnection(login, password, connection_string);
}
```

If I use connection_string:

```
string connection_string1 = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 
" + host_ + ")(PORT = " + port_ + "))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = " + sid_ + ")))";
```

which is created using some variables, I got this exception:

> ORA-12163: TNS:connect descriptor is too long

If I use the same string, but like:

```
string connection_string2 = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = 'TCP')(HOST 
= 'real.host.I.need.cz')(PORT = '1510'))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = 'word')))";
```

with actual values, I got other exception:

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

(`connection_string1 == connection_string2` returns TRUE)

If I use `""`(empty string) or `"f"`(anything), I got

> ORA-12163: TNS:connect descriptor is too long

. This can't be true.

How can I find out, where the problem is?

Comment: Step one; post a [mcve].

Comment: the only difference between the code above and the code in my Visual Studio is that my code contains actual values. I'm sure you understand that I'm not gonna post my login and my password

Comment: Not that I know anything about occi, but a google search suggests it's maybe a library problem. Are you using the correct libraries for your compiler from here? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were connecting to server of version 11, but using Instant Client Version 12.2.0.1.0.

Using [Instant Client Version 11.2.0.4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/downloads/index.html)  solved the problem.